# How can I use functions to complete the following table? I came close to having it solved, but I'm getting exception errors

Tags: java, function, exception, degrees, radians

[Code on SoloLearn Part 1][Code on SoloLearn Part 2][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYz5H.png)[My Take Home Assignment [][1][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax4vD.jpg)`
[Radians, Tangent, Sine, Cosine, and Degrees Table

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class St_Johns_University
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Radians", "Tangent", "Sine", "Cosine", "Degrees");

        int degrees = 60;
        double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10d%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 80;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10d%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 100;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10d%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 130;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10d%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 160;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    System.out.printf("%-10d%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting using print f is wrong. Also import of Scanner is not required.
degree is int but you have provided `f` instead of `d` and also provided precision 4. radians is double. but you have provided `d` which is wrong
 I have corrected it please check the below code.

```
public class St_Johns_University
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Radians", "Tangent", "Sine", "Cosine", "Degrees");

        int degrees = 60;
        double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10d\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 80;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10d\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 100;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10d\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 130;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        System.out.printf("%-10f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10d\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
         degrees = 160;
         radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
         System.out.printf("%-10f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10.4f%-10d\n", radians, Math.tan(radians), Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians), degrees);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your problem is solved please accept this answer. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers